# WebKit. Hover on image 'alt' not working

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit

I have really simple HTML code

```
<img class='star' src='' alt='&#9733;'/>
```

With really simple style

```
.star {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black;
}

.star:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

My idia is this. If there is no image on server, I show unicode star symbol ( or if user will switch off all images ). And if a user

It works perfectly in FF ( tested on FF25 ) but fails really hard on WebKit browsers. Hover state dosn't trigger or triggers ones and then stay in that state forever.

**I have only one question.. WTF is that? o_O Where am I wrong, or it's just a WebKit bug?**

It would be nice if someone told me how to fix this. But mostly i want to understand what is going on here.

PS: Example http://jsbin.com/UMIrAJI/3/edit

**UPD:**

This example is working http://jsbin.com/UMIrAJI/5/edit but the only difference is 'background' color changed on hover. As soon as we remove 'background' - hover stops working. LOL.

So my question is still valid. What is going on here?

**UPD2:**

I found another workaround. If we add `border: 0px solid white;` (but only on hover) example will also start to work  http://jsbin.com/UMIrAJI/6/edit . So it's something about repainting.

**UPD3:**
It looks like a bug to me so I reported it. I'll wait for some comments from developers.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=323545&thanks=323545&ts=1385479799

Comment: I think works for me in Chrome IE9 and FF http://jsbin.com/UMIrAJI/5/

Comment: @Danko WOW.. now remove 'background', and tell me what you see, plz

Comment: Oh id don't know why it works only with bg let me search about this

Comment: @Danko BTW, I found another workaround. If we add `border: 0px solid white;` (but only on hover) example will also start to work  http://jsbin.com/UMIrAJI/6/edit . So it's something about repainting.

Comment: Given the comments above, it certainly sounds like a browser bug. Would be worth reporting it.

Comment: @Ai_boy yes a good one bug even if you set border 0 it works ..

Comment: @Danko - done for Chrome  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=323545&thanks=323545&ts=1385479799 need help with WebKit (I just don't know where to report to)

Comment: Good one only your report says this doesn't work in other browsers but works in FF

Comment: Tnx for mentioning that. I added a comment that mentions that FF is working properly in this case.

Comment: doesn't work on chrome as well :/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alt, which should describe the content of the image, for browsers without image support and for accessibility tools, use the title property

```
<img class='star' src='' title='&#9733;'/>
```

Comment: I don't think we need to press -1, for that answer, but @JoeriHendrickx is correct. I'm not asking about tooltips.

Comment: he is actually asking about hover text, as the alt tag is not to be used for what he wants to do, and chrome treats it correctly by not showing it since it is already showing the image.

Comment: @DusteD He's not showing the image.  He's asking about the text that is shown when the image is not available.  Which is alt.  Title is (generally) displayed in the tooltip.  He's not interested in the tooltip.